# Display Duration for Multiple Videos on a Page

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video, metadata

I'm trying to display "duration" for each video on the page using JavaScript.
here is what I've come up with so far:

```js
var vid = document.querySelector(".mhdividdur");
vid.onloadedmetadata = function() {
  var x = document.querySelector(".mhdividdur").duration;
document.querySelector(".mhdi_video_duration").innerHTML = x;
};
```

```html
<video class="mhdividdur" width="240px" controls preload="metadata" poster="http://cdn1.ko.cowa.ir//kocofeaturedimage.jpg">
<source src="http://cdn1.ko.cowa.ir//hwasa.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
<p class="mhdi_video_duration"></p>
<video class="mhdividdur" width="240px" controls preload="metadata" poster="http://cdn1.ko.cowa.ir//kocofeaturedimage.jpg">
<source src="http://cdn1.ko.cowa.ir//numb.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
<p class="mhdi_video_duration"></p>
```

The problem is that it only returns the duration for the 1st video.

What should I do?

P.S. If there are any other ways except JavaScript to display duration, please give me a hint.

Thank You all

Comment: Instead of querySelector use getElementsByClassName which will return array of elements and you can loop through it and update the duration for each one of them.

Comment: i have done this but didn't work! :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with `querySelector` function you can get the first of the elements that match the selector you entered. that's why you need to get all the video elements with `querySelectorAll` function which will return an array of elements and loop to print their duration.

```js
var videos = document.querySelectorAll(".mhdividdur");
var durationsEl = document.querySelectorAll(".mhdi_video_duration");
for(let i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
  videos[i].onloadedmetadata = function() {
    durationsEl[i].innerHTML = videos[i].duration;
  };
}
```

```html
<video class="mhdividdur" width="240px" controls preload="metadata" poster="http://cdn1.ko.cowa.ir//kocofeaturedimage.jpg">
<source src="http://cdn1.ko.cowa.ir//hwasa.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
<p class="mhdi_video_duration"></p>
<video class="mhdividdur" width="240px" controls preload="metadata" poster="http://cdn1.ko.cowa.ir//kocofeaturedimage.jpg">
<source src="http://cdn1.ko.cowa.ir//numb.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
<p class="mhdi_video_duration"></p>
```

Comment: sorry, I am a total rookie. I just copy pasted this and nothing happend! even the duration doesn't show up for the 1st video. would you mind helping me through this?